# How to send child objects to an MVC view in a list of parent objects

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, inheritance, collections

say I have these classes:

```
public class Animal
{

}

public class Elephant : Animal
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and I have a controller method

```
    public SubmitElephants()
{
    var elephants = new List<Animal>();

    elephants.Add(new Elephant { Name = "Timmy" };
    elephants.Add(new Elephant { Name = "Michael" };

return View("DisplayElephants", elephants);

}
```

The DisplayElephants view looks like:

```
@model IList<Elephant>

@foreach(var elephant in Model)
{
  <div>@elephant.Name</div>
}
```

So if I run this code I will get the error:

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Animal]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[Elephant]'

So no I'm NOT wanting to change my list to be `var elephants = new List<Elephant>();`

What I'm wanting to know given I have a list of Animals that I know contains only Elephants how can I from the controller pass this to a view which is specific to Elephants?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK this is not possible. What you are attempting is opposite of Covariance, in a sense.

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ee207183.aspx) describes Covariance and Contravariance.

In summary, you could do this -

```
IEnumerable<Elephant> elephants = new List<Elephant>();
IEnumerable<Animal> animals = elephants;
```

You actually want the other way around.

Also note that not all generic collections are covariant. [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/dd233059.aspx) tells us the collections that are covariant in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
var elephants = new List<Animal>();
```

to:

```
var elephants = new List<Elephant>();
```

For more info on why this is, see @Srikanth's answer.